# MomentJS - convert datetime from UTC to different timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trygin to convert utc time to local timezone with moment but without success.. Here is my code:

```
var utc = moment.tz('2017-03-28 15:00:00','UTC');
var s = utc.format();
var pl = moment.tz(utc.format(), 'Europe/Warsaw').format();
console.info(s);
console.info(pl);
```

and the output is:

```
VM4496:4 2017-03-28T15:00:00Z
VM4496:5 2017-03-28T17:00:00+02:00
```

As you can see, moment adds 2 hours to UTC, but `Europe/Warsaw` is in `UTC+1` time zone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you can see, moment adds 2 hours to UTC, but `Europe/Warsaw` is in `UTC+1` time zone

Not on March 28th. On March 28th, it's UTC+2, because of Daylight Savings Time, which [starts on March 26th in Warsaw](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/poland/warsaw) and runs through October 29th.

> OK, other question: how to make it to skip Daylight Savings time?

Use the the `Etc/GMT-1` timezone. Yes, really -1. It's horrible and wrong, but apparently, that's GMT+1 (!!!) in the tz database (which is used by [but not controlled by] Moment-Timezone) which uses that notation because of some POSIX convention. The `Etc/GMT` timezones have their sign reversed. Ugh. Details [here](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/277) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area).

If that makes you uncomfortable, you could add your own timezone:

```
moment.tz.add([
    'Own/UTC+1|+01|10|0|'
]);
```

Example:

```js
moment.tz.add([
  'Own/UTC+1|+01|-10|0|'
]);
var utc = moment.tz('2017-03-28 15:00:00','UTC');
var s = utc.format();
var plusOne = moment.tz(utc.format(), 'Etc/GMT-1').format();
var own = moment.tz(utc.format(), 'Own/UTC+1').format();
console.info(s);
console.info(plusOne);
console.info(own);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly. In most of Europe, unlike the US, on the last Sunday of March, 3 am, local time is advanced by 1 hour to 4 am due to the changeover from standard time to daylight savings time.

Comment: OK, other question: how to make it to skip Daylight Savings time?

Comment: You need to use Central European Standard Time or Central European Normal time,. CEST / CENT (CEST is more common), instead of Centrel European Time. 'Europe/Warsaw' is probably not the best way to fetch the time zone, the API certainly has more advanced possibilities?

Comment: .utcOffset('+0100') - but that's the n fixed. Should Poland ever move to e.g. a fixed +0130, then that's broken.