# MomentJS convert from UTC to desired timezone, not just local

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using momentjs but having an issue trying to convert a UTC time to a specific timezone (not necessarily local to the current user) that is specified by name `'America/New_York'`. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994421/momentjs-convert-datetime-from-utc-to-different-timezone) is similar but didn't really help.

My thought process is to create a utc moment obj with the received date from the server and then format that UTC time to the specific timezone for display purposes. A small snippet of how I'm currently approaching this:

```
var cutoffString = '20170421 16:30:00'; // in utc
var utcCutoff = moment.tz(cutoffString, 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss', '+00:00');
var displayCutoff = 
        moment.tz(utcCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss'), 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss', 'America/New_York');

console.log('utcCutoff:', utcCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ssa Z')); // => utcCutoff: 20170421 04:30:00pm +00:00
console.log('displayCutoff:', displayCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ssa Z')); // => displayCutoff: 20170421 04:30:00pm +00:00
```

My assumption here is that displayCutoff would be the utcCutoff time displayed in 'America/New_York' time. But it currently is displays the same time as the utcCutoff object. I also should mention that using `.utc()` instead of `.tz` and trying to manipulate the timezone after applying `.local()` did not work either.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43113350/4131048) an example on how convert moment between timezone that could help you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) since your input is an UTC string. You can use [`tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) to convert your moment object to a given timezone.

Please note that the [`tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) function converts moment object to a given zone, while you are using [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) parsing function that builds a new moment object with the given zone. When you do:

```
var displayCutoff = 
    moment.tz(utcCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss'), 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss', 'America/New_York');
```

you are not converting `utcCutoff` to `'America/New_York'` but you are building a new moment object for `20170421 16:30:00` in New York.

Here an updated version of your code:

```js
var cutoffString = '20170421 16:30:00'; // in utc
var utcCutoff = moment.utc(cutoffString, 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss');
var displayCutoff = utcCutoff.clone().tz('America/New_York');

console.log('utcCutoff:', utcCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ssa Z')); // => utcCutoff: 20170421 04:30:00pm +00:00
console.log('displayCutoff:', displayCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ssa Z')); // => displayCutoff: 20170421 12:30:00pm -04:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. One thing I noted is that the cdn I was pointing to for moment-timezone 0.5.13 did not have the data included and therefore was still displaying the time in UTC with your solution. When I added the latest packed data, things worked as your sample did.

Comment: This is basically what is SO unclear from the momentJs documentation. Many thanks Vicenzo.

Answer (score 6):

Moment timezone plugin is exactly what you need : http://momentjs.com/timezone/

```
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");
dec.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');  // 5am PDT
```

Comment: If it's 12:00 in UTC time, surely it cannot be 05:00 in New York time. PDT is the timezone on the west coast.

Answer (score 6):

With `momentjs-timezone` you can convert from any timezone to any other timezone.

You need to specify the start time zone and before formatting the target timezone.

Here is an example which converts a date time from UTC to three other timezones:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

const start = moment.tz("2021-12-08T10:00:00", "UTC") // original timezone

console.log(start.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format())
console.log(start.tz("Asia/Calcutta").format())
console.log(start.tz("Canada/Eastern").format())
```

This will print out:

```
2021-12-08T02:00:00-08:00
2021-12-08T15:30:00+05:30
2021-12-08T05:00:00-05:00
```

Instead of UTC as start timezone you can use any other timezone too, like "Asia/Seoul" and obviously get different results with the same script:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

const start = moment.tz("2021-12-08T10:00:00", "Asia/Seoul")

console.log(start.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format())
console.log(start.tz("Asia/Calcutta").format())
console.log(start.tz("Canada/Eastern").format())
```

This prints out:

```
2021-12-07T17:00:00-08:00
2021-12-08T06:30:00+05:30
2021-12-07T20:00:00-05:00
```

All momentjs timezones are listed here:

https://gist.github.com/diogocapela/12c6617fc87607d11fd62d2a4f42b02a

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [moment .parseZone 2.3.0+](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) is what you need:

```
const inputDate = '2023-05-28T00:00:00+11:00';
const parsedDate = moment(inputDate);
console.log(parsedDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY')); // 27/05/2023
parsedDate.parseZone();
console.log(parsedDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY')); // 28/05/2023
```

Answer (score -4):

> There is no need to use MomentJs to convert your timezone to specific timezone. Just follow my given  below code, it will work for you :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   //EST
setInterval( function() {
var estTime = new Date();
 var currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone = new Date(estTime.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Chicago' }));
var seconds = currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getSeconds();
var minutes = currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getMinutes();
var hours =  currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getHours();//new Date().getHours();
 var am_pm = currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";

if (hours < 10){
     hours = "0" + hours;
}

if (minutes < 10){
     minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
if (seconds < 10){
     seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
    var mid='PM';
    if(hours==0){ //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
    hours=12;
    }
    else if(hours>12)
    {
    hours=hours%12;
    mid='AM';
    }
    var x3 = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds +' '+am_pm
// Add a leading zero to seconds value
$("#sec").html(x3);
},1000);


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p class="date_time"><strong id="sec"></strong>  </p>


</body>
</html>
```