# Convert utc timestamp to local time using offset In seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs, timezone-offset

I need to convert utc timestamp to local time using utc offset in seconds. i had used moment-timezone library. This is my code

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var timestamp = Date.now();

var IST1 = moment(timestamp).utcOffset('+05:30').format('ddd MMM D Y hh:mm:ss A ')
console.log("IST1 '+05:30' --> ", IST1);

var IST2 = moment(timestamp).utcOffset('+19800').format('ddd MMM D Y hh:mm:ss A ')
console.log("IST2 '+19800' --> ", IST2);
```

But i got output like this

```
IST1 '+05:30' -->  Mon Jun 19 2017 01:39:23 PM 
IST2 '+19800' -->  Tue Jun 20 2017 04:29:23 AM
```

Using '+05:30', i got correct time. But using '+19800' , i got wrong time. What is the actual issue related with this code?

Comment: Why are you using `utcOffset`? Moment by default parses time in local time, if you need to convert time to given timezone you can use [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) function.

Comment: i need to convert time in different regions(eg: IST,PDT..etc)

Comment: Since you have to _"convert time in different regions"_ I still think that you have to use [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) instead of `utcOffset`. You can have something like `moment(timestamp).tz("Asia/Kolkata")` for `IST` and `moment(timestamp).tz("America/Los_Angeles")` for `PDT`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43113350/4131048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43525786/4131048) for same examples.

Comment: i have already tested with timezone regions. But in my case, my inputs are timestamp & its timezone offset in seconds. Thats y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/), it looks like the function `utcOffset` takes minutes as params and not seconds.

Try using

```
var IST2 = moment(timestamp)
    .utcOffset('+330')
    .format('ddd MMM D Y hh:mm:ss A ')
```

and it should work.

Comment: i have successfully got the result like this "Wed Jul 5 2017 11:29:56 AM". Is it possible to getting timezone with this.? eg "Wed Jul 5 2017 11:29:56 AM IST"