# How to get seconds, mins, hrs, days using TZ Format?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a little project that returns a date format like: `2021-04-25T08:34:08.3415879-05:00`
However I'm wanting to work out the time since the last date format which is like above, and also have it converted to GMT + 0 timezone.

What I have so far

```js
var startDate = new Date("2021-04-25T08:34:08.3415879-05:00");
var endDate   = new Date();
var seconds = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000;
```

Comment: [what about this ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525786/momentjs-convert-from-utc-to-desired-timezone-not-just-local)

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this-

```js
function displaytime {
  local T=$1
  local D=$((T/60/60/24))
  local H=$((T/60/60%24))
  local M=$((T/60%60))
  local S=$((T%60))
  (( $D > 0 )) && printf '%d days ' $D
  (( $H > 0 )) && printf '%d hours ' $H
  (( $M > 0 )) && printf '%d minutes ' $M
  (( $D > 0 || $H > 0 || $M > 0 )) && printf 'and '
  printf '%d seconds\n' $S
}
```

Comment: `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'",`